# Wedges with label parameter, but none label in result

Tags: python, matplotlib, wedge

I am beginner with python (3.4) and matplotlib. I want to create a wedge with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax1.add_patch(patches.Wedge(center=(0,0), r=0.9, theta1=90, theta2=120, facecolor="red", label="Test"))
plt.xlim(-1, 1)
plt.ylim(-1, 1)
fig1.savefig('wedge1.png', dpi=90, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

All Looks fine, but the Label isn't in the plot? Any idea?

[image: Chart with no Label???]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `plt.legend()`. You just need to add it anywhere before the `plt.show` (also before `fig1.savefig` if you want it saved in the image) and after all your plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax1.add_patch(patches.Wedge(center=(0,0), r=0.9, theta1=90, theta2=120, facecolor="red", label="Test"))
plt.xlim(-1, 1)
plt.ylim(-1, 1)
plt.legend()  # <--- here
fig1.savefig('wedge1.png', dpi=90, bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Have a look here for further details on [how to use legends](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html).

Comment: Thank you. Simple, but you must know it.

Comment: @Geosucher Yep, indeed. I would suggest you (in case you are interested), to have a look to the [scipy's matplotlib lecture notes](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/matplotlib/matplotlib.html). They are a series of lecture notes that include an overview of all-you-need from matplotlib (in this case, they have more lecture notes) to use the most of it. Also, please consider upvoting/accepting the answer in case it helped you.